# HereMap for WPF desktop application

Tags: here-api

I want to use HERE Maps in a WPF application. How can I implement it? Which API and which Control should I use?Please share some basic example.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this open topic. Did you have a look for the JavaScript API? You could embed this into your application.

Further information can be sound here:
https://developer.here.com/develop/javascript-api

Besides of that you can also use the HTTPRest interfaces for map display (common tiling schema), Routing, Geocoder etc.